# How to create new review for local changes in upsource?

Tags: svn, jetbrains-ide, upsource

I want to create new review for my local changelist without commit in SVN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upsource only supports post-commit code review. If it's not in the repository, there's no way to create a review. You can vote up this feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-1602.